# Why is the string property added to f-curve read-only

Tags: python, scripting, properties

When I create a string property for the object type, I can modify that property in the active object. But when I create another string property for the f-curve type, it said it is read-only.

The script:

```py
import bpy
bpy.types.Object.objprop = bpy.props.StringProperty(name = "objString")
bpy.context.object.objprop = "mod_objString"

bpy.types.FCurve.fprop = bpy.props.StringProperty(name = "fString")
bpy.context.object.animation_data.action.fcurves[0].fprop = "mod_fString" # error occured on this line
```

error:

[image: error]

some testing in the built in python interpreter:

[image: in built in python interpreter]

Edit: 
The blend file (although it is almost empty but just in case):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **[Assigning to Existing Classes](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#assigning-to-existing-classes)**
>
> Custom properties can be added to any subclass of an `ID`, `Bone` and
> `PoseBone`

Neither are bones, so leaving that aside, can see below `ID` is subclass of `Object` not `FCurve`, and as such is the property is not "wired up" as a property on the fcurve.

```
>>> issubclass(bpy.types.Object, (bpy.types.ID,))
True

>>> issubclass(bpy.types.FCurve, (bpy.types.ID,))
False
```

another test for this would be trying to assign ID properties to an instance.  This is how a non default value of a property is stored in blend file.

For example, for an `Object` type

```
>>> C.object["foo"] = 1
```

but not for an `FCurve`

```
>>> D.actions['CubeAction'].fcurves[0]
bpy.data.actions['CubeAction']...FCurve

>>> D.actions['CubeAction'].fcurves[0]["foo"] = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bpy_struct[key] = val: id properties not supported for this type
```

Comment: thanks, so is there other ways I could store properties in individual fcurves?

Comment: Off top of head could use collection property on action. Give item a `datapath` and `array_index` to lookup from `FCurve`.